# Diode ROM with decoder and multiplexers

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, memory, rom

I have this question on my exam I couldn't answer:

A diode ROM has been built using a decoder and multiplexers. If A4A3A2A1A0 = 01001, what is D3D2D1D0?

Here is the first schematic:

[image]

The answer is supposed to be:

[image]

Can anyone explain the solution?

Comment: Can you first explain which part you don't understand?

Comment: I am getting answer 0100, not 0101 ...Again I am not sure about the dot convention used here...Whether cathode or anode  represents that dot.

Comment: Are you on the same address line as the answer? Or you didn’t make it that far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people do this before, it's really strange and was far more common back in the 80s (or earlier) when memory was really, really expensive and programs were short.

The general concept is you run your address lines to a demultiplexer (or inverting demultiplexer, as in this case) and have a pull-up resistor from every data line to 5V. You then place a diode in every spot you want to be a 0 (depending on address, like a memory) when you want that bit in your program to be a '0' at a certain address from the non-fixed side of the pull-up resistor to that output of the demultiplexer.

When the demultiplexer output is low, current will run through the pull-up resistor and diode and since the diode forward voltage drop is 0.7V it will be under the 0.8V required for a logic '0' but when the demulitplexer output is high no current runs through that leg of the circuit and it is high.

It's an incredibly difficult concept to describe in a text box, see this article: http://www.wintergroundfairlands.com/2013/10/visualizing-roms-1-diode-matrix-rom.html

Comment: These date back to the 60's, by the 70's PROMs (both MOS and bipolar) were common so diode matrices were not used much.